# Set HighCharts data from JSON string with setData() function

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I try to update a HighCharts with `setData()` method with data from a successfully ajax response:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "createHighChartsContent.do",
    data: "document=Test",
    success: function(data) {           
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        $("#chart01").highcharts().series[0].setData([data]);
    }
});


<div style="font-size: 2px; font-family: Verdana; margin-bottom:0px;">  
    <div id="chart01" style="height: 732px; margin: 0 auto"></div>   
</div>
```

The servlet which creates the response looks like this:

```
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) {    
        String json = new Gson().toJson("{x:1406199133117,y:5,name:'Test'}");
        try {
            resp.getWriter().write(json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

**Problem:**

The HighChart instance is not updated.

If I try to set the data in ajax response manually:

```
$j("#chart01").highcharts().series[0].setData([{x:1406199133117,y:5,name:'Test'}])
```

it is working like expected.

Whats wrong here?

**Edit:**

So, yes the JSON string is not valid. I try it with SteveP changes but it does not work.

I think the main problem is that setData() needs an array with a valid JavaScript **OBJECT**.

Following code is working:

```
var s = {x:1406199133117,y:5,name:'Test'};
console.log(s);
var arr = [];
arr.push(s);
$("#chart01").highcharts().series[0].setData(arr);
```

JavaScript console shows `Object {x: 1406199133117, y: 5, name: "Test"}`

I did not get it working to create such a object from the ajax data response.

The HighChart is created this way:

```
$("#chart01").highcharts({
       chart: {
          //renderTo: "chart01",
          type: 'bar'
       },
       title: {
         text: ''
       },
       xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          dateTimeLabelFormats: {
             week: '%e. %b %Y'   
          },
          offset: 10,
          maxZoom: 7 * 24 * 3600000 // seven days
       },
       yAxis: {
          title: {              
             text: 'Defects Count'              
          },
          minTickInterval: 1
       },
       plotOptions: {
          series: {
             stacking: 'normal'
          }              
       },
       series: [              
            { name:'Test', data: [] }
       ]
    });
```

Comment: Did you get value in `console.log(data)`? Also, could you provide an insight of your script tags (for highcharts) that is added?

Comment: Yes, it looks like this: {x:1406199133117,y:5,name:'Test'}

Comment: thats correct. Array is the param for [setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series--setData)

Comment: But it does not work so far...also if I push "data" into an array and pass this array to setData().

Comment: Once you create a `JSON.parse` in the response, could you avoid the adding to array like this `setData([data]);` and just do `setData(data)`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what's going wrong here, but there are a few things I am concerned about.

Firstly, your JSON is not valid. x, y and name should be quoted:

```
{ "x": 1406199133117, "y": 5, "name": "Test" }
```

I am concerned about:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson("{x:1406199133117,y:5,name:'Test'}");
```

Why not simply write the string ?

```
resp.getWriter().write("{\"x\":1406199133117,\"y\":5,\"name\":'Test'}");
```

Lastly, I would return the entire array, including the [] braces rather than adding them in the client.

Hopefully some of that helps :)